# How to fix bytes unrepaired in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-4.0

Could you please explain what i do wrong?
I'm running 7 nodes in one DC of Cassandra 4.0.5 As I'm trying to maintain those nodes I'm running on daily basis on every node:

`nodetool repair --full -pr <keyspace>`

As I understand the "Bytes unrepaired" value should be decreasing, not increasing, but it's  not work for me. Instead of decreasing I got this:

`nodetool tablestats <keyspace> | grep -E "Table:|Bytes unrepaired:"`

```
    Table: <table1>
    Percent repaired: 0.0
    Bytes repaired: 0.000KiB
    Bytes unrepaired: 31.304GiB
    Table: <table2>
    Percent repaired: 0.0
    Bytes repaired: 0.000KiB
    Bytes unrepaired: 1009.825GiB
    Table: <table3>
    Percent repaired: 100.0
    Bytes repaired: 0.000KiB
    Bytes unrepaired: 0.000KiB
    Table: <table4>
    Percent repaired: 0.0
    Bytes repaired: 0.000KiB
    Bytes unrepaired: 2.227GiB
    Table: <table5>
    Percent repaired: 0.0
    Bytes repaired: 0.000KiB
    Bytes unrepaired: 250.537GiB
    Percent repaired: 0.0
    Bytes repaired: 0.000KiB
    Bytes unrepaired: 4.364MiB
    Table: <table6>
    Percent repaired: 0.0
    Bytes repaired: 0.000KiB
    Bytes unrepaired: 1.227MiB
    Table: <table7>
    Percent repaired: 0.0
    Bytes repaired: 0.000KiB
    Bytes unrepaired: 2.031MiB
```

Answer (score 1):

The term "unrepaired" may seem ambiguous given what [repairs](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.1/cassandra/operating/repair.html#incremental-and-full-repairs) are meant to do, but what you see is expected.

The distinction between repaired and unrepaired bytes lies in the metadata upon which incremental repairs depend.

**FULL REPAIR**

When you run the repair command you issued (in 4.0 and above) with `--full`, Cassandra doesn't mark the data covered by the scope of the repair as "repaired" at the sstable metadata level, keeping the default "unrepaired" state - this makes the distinction between `full` and `incremental` repairs.

**INCREMENTAL REPAIR**

When you run an incremental repair instead, Cassandra marks all the repaired data as "repaired", also at the sstable level - The goal of this feature is to skip the "repaired" sstables in future repair sessions, minimizing repair overhead.
This effectively creates 2 pools of sstables behind the scenes, where repaired sstables can only be compacted with other repaired sstables, while the same logic applies to their unrepaired counterparts, in order to retain the consistency of repair status metadata.

---

So that you don't have to be locked in into only **full** or **incremental** repairs, Cassandra always keeps the repaired metadata accordingly, depending on which repair strategy you opt for.

Reportedly, previous bugs with incremental repairs were addressed in Cassandra 4.0, and in most cases it's worth running incremental repairs in Cassandra 4 and above, with some periodic full repairs in between. This is specially true if repair runs impact your services/application - incremental repairs can save you a ton of repair time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you please tell me if I am understanding correctly if I do full repair in 7 days and incremental repair every day or I don't know, 6 days incremental and on the 7th day full repair, the number of "unrepaired" will decrease?

Comment: In theory that's correct. Every time you run an incremental repair, more data is going to be marked as "repaired". Although, running it on a daily basis may be too conservative. It depends on the `gc_grace_seconds` - if this is set to 1 day for a table, then you should definitively repair that table daily.

Either way, you shouldn't worry much on whether or not the data is marked as "unrepaired" - its value doesn't literally mean it isn't repaired. Every time you run a repair, full or incremental, be sure that all of the unrepaired data gets repaired no matter what `tablestats` tells you.

Comment: Thank you! Now I will try not to run a full repair every day, but only once a week on Sunday and Monday through Saturday incremental. As I understood it will be enough